# using objective-c open a new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am totally new with `iOS` development.I am just trying to open a new page when user will click on button. But it is not working.I am using this code:

```
(IBAction)btnOpenNewPage:(UIButton *)sender {   
    FacebookViewController *ls=[[FacebookViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginSuccessViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ls animated:YES];
}
```

But i don't understand why it is not working! I am using `Xcode 6`. I think i need to add some parameter or code in other files. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you're acutally using a UINavigationController in your app?

Comment: Have you read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS"? If not, read it before writing any more code.

Answer (score 0):

if your code there doesn't work then you probably don't have a navigationController. try creating one:

```
-(IBAction)btnOpenNewPage:(UIButton *)sender {   

FacebookViewController *ls=[[FacebookViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginSuccessViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Is];


[nav pushViewController:ls animated:YES];
}
```